# ASP.NET MVC URL Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to make a redirect for my MVC website. Currently I have a URL that looks like:

```
www.domain.com/site/user?id=23&session=5
```

I want to make a redirect that will always map to that URL so:

```
www.domain.com/info
```

will direct to

```
www.domain.com/site/user?id=23&session=5
```

I want the `www.domain.com/home` to always redirect to `www.domain.com/site/user?id=23&session=5`

Does anyone know how to do this? thanks.

Comment: `if (url ==  "www.domain.com/info") { url = "www.domain.com/site/user?id=23&session=5"; }`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be overthinking it.

Why not just add in a method that checks the url?

```
if (url == "www.domain.com/info")
    url = "www.domain.com/site/user?id=23&session=5";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC 4 or MVC 5 then use attribute routing concept to achieve this requirement.
Use [RoutePrefix] Or [Route] attributes for controller and action metods